# parsing a set of input files by javacc

Tags: javacc

I can use javacc to parse a single file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                        pathFile));
if (parser == null)
    parser = new MaNouvGrammaire(br);
else
    MaNouvGrammaire.ReInit(br);
```

my question is: *"How I can parse several input files?"*

Comment: I don't think the code you show in fact parses anything. It just instantiates the parser. Also what do you mean by ;how can I parse multiple files'? If you have code to parse one file you can just put that in a loop no? Or do you mean that you want to parse multiple files re-using the same parser instance? You probably need to fixup this question to a) provide a better code snippet and b) clarify what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response
in reality, I would parse a file that contains another the  same file type.

for example: the file 1 contains the source code in which there is a call of the file 2.

how I can parse a file who call  another file.  is in my file .jjt or .jj file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it if you use the STATIC=false option.
Use a loop:

```
while( <there are more files> ) {
    File pathFile = <next file> ;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
    MaNouvGrammaire parser = new MaNouvGrammaire(br);
    paser.start() ; // or whatever your start nonterminal is
```

}

With the STATIC = true option, I think it is something like what you had

```
while( <there are more files> ) {
     File pathFile = <next file> ;
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathFile));
     if (parser == null)
        parser = new MaNouvGrammaire(br);
     else
        MaNouvGrammaire.ReInit(br);
     parser.start() ; // or whatever your start nonterminal is
}
```

In addition, make sure that `parser` is declared as a static member of the class initialized to `null`.

Both should work. Nonstatic parsers are slightly more straightforward to initialize, as seen above. Also non static parsers work with multithreaded uses and recursive uses (e.g. recursively reading include files).

Comment: thank you very much about your response. but , I did not understand this statement:
  while (<There are more files>)

how I can implementer,   thank you

Comment: I have no idea how your set of files is accessed, so that's just a place-holder. Fill it in as appropriate. E.g. you might use `for( File f : ListOfFiles) {...}`.